# Remove SSL from Google Search results

Tags: google-search, 301-redirect, https, cloudflare

I am working on a WordPress site that serves up HTTP pages statically. The problem is that some of the pages are shown as HTTPS in Google Search results. For instance, if the search term "*Example Press Kit*" is entered the search result site link comes up as:

```
https://example.com/presskit/
```

We don't have a site SSL certificate, so surfers are being bounced. I have tried everything. Most recently I created a new website in Google WebAdmin for the HTTPS version of our home page. Then, I added site links that should have redirected site links intended for `https://example.com/*` to `http://example.com/*`, but it doesn't work! Google still shows a dead link to `http://example.com/presskit`. I didn't think dead links lasted very long on Google results, but there they are, two weeks later.

Any ideas? A `301 redirect` won't work because the site doesn't even allow redirection from HTTPS. It is served by CloudFlare.

Comment: Why would you use hosting that doesn't allow redirects? That's not hosting.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach to resolve the issues:

- Redirect `https://` with a 301 to `http://`. You can do this with your *.htaccess* or with WordPress plugins. Just do a search on WordPress plugins or Google. Here's a link that might be helpful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717799/redirecting-https-to-http-via-htaccess.
- Once you have your redirects setup you should log in to your Google account and request that the `https://` URLs be removed. Google will actually do that eventually with the redirect in place, but you can speed it up a bit by doing it manually.

Comment: How can I request the the https URLs be removed? Is this in Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: Yes in your Webmaster Tools account.